# bitwise shift for a string holding a numeric hex. in perl

Tags: perl, hex

I have a string

```
$string = "0x0"
```

Now I want to basically use this string as a number and do a bitwise shift i.e my aim is to

```
$C = $string <<4 ;
```

But when I do this it says :

```
Argument "0x0" isn't numeric in left bitshift (<<)
```

Can someone please help to execute this ?

Comment: Hex is a *string* representation of a number. `<<` requires a number.

Answer (score 4):

It's because "0x0" isn't numeric. It's a string. You would have to turn it into a numeric value.

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $string = "0x0";
 my $number = hex($string);
 my $C = $number <<4 ;
 print $C;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you have to convert it to a *numeric* value and use `sprintf` to turn back to a *hexadecimal* value.

```
sprintf ("0x%x" , hex($string) << 4);
```

Answer (score -1):

Perl converts strings to numbers by looking for a leading sign character, decimal digits, or a single decimal point. When it runs into a non-decimal digit or a second decimal point, it stops. This also means that a leading 0 is just another decimal digit and not an octal indicator. Since neither `b`, `o`, or `x` are any of those characters, Perl stops processing when it encounters them.

```
$ perl -le 'print 0 + shift' 0x37
0

$ perl -le 'print 0 + shift' 37
37

$ perl -le 'print 0 + shift' 1.2.3
1.2

$ perl -le 'print 0 + shift' -- -123fred
-123
```

If your string has a hex number, an octal number, or a binary number, convert it with Perl's built-in functions that tell it which base to look for:

- [hex](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex)
- [oct](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct)

Some examples (all command-line arguments are strings):

```
$ perl -le 'print hex(shift)' 0x37
55

$ perl -le 'print hex(shift)' 37
55

$ perl -le 'print hex(shift)' ab
171

$ perl -le 'print oct(shift)' 37
31

$ perl -le 'print oct(shift)' 037
31

$ perl -le 'print oct(shift)' 0o37
31
```

Now, there's another curious feature. For historical reasons that are entirely inconsistent today, the [oct](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct) function recognizes all the the prefixes (including the [octal prefix `0o` added in v5.34](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2021/03/specify-octal-numbers-with-the-0o-prefix/)):

```
$ perl -le 'print oct(shift)' 0x37
55

$ perl -le 'print oct(shift)' 0o37
31

$ perl -le 'print oct(shift)' 0b111
7

$ perl -le 'print oct(shift)' 0123
83

$ perl -le 'print oct(shift)' 123
83
```

For a bonus, the `looks_like_number` from the core [Scalar::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar::Util) module can tell you what Perl thinks is a completely a recognized decimal number:

```
$ perl -MScalar::Util -le 'print Scalar::Util::looks_like_number(shift) ? "Yes" : "No"' 0o37
No

$ perl -MScalar::Util -le 'print Scalar::Util::looks_like_number(shift) ? "Yes" : "No"' 0x55
No

$ perl -MScalar::Util -le 'print Scalar::Util::looks_like_number(shift) ? "Yes" : "No"' 137
Yes

$ perl -MScalar::Util -le 'print Scalar::Util::looks_like_number(shift) ? "Yes" : "No"' 1.2.3
No

$ perl -MScalar::Util -le 'print Scalar::Util::looks_like_number(shift) ? "Yes" : "No"' -- -1.2
Yes
```

Answer (score -2):

if the shifts needed is already a multiple of 4, then just pad trailing `0`s to the existing hex instead of decoding it then re-`sprintf()`-ing it.